# Shiny selectInput not highlighting choices blue on hover

Tags: r, shiny

For some reason, `selectInput()` no longer highlights choices when hovering or when navigating with up and down arrows. How do I reenable this behavior?

This is what I see:

[image]

This is what I expect to see:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to use `pickerInput()`. This works:

```r
library(shiny)

css <- "
.selectize-item {
  color: black;
}
.selectize-option {
  color: black;
}
.selectize-option:hover {
  background-color: #337AB7;
  color: white
}

"

render <- I("
{
  item: function(item, escape) { 
    return '<div class=\"item selectize-item\">' + escape(item.label) + '</div>'; 
  },
  option: function(item, escape) {
    return '<div class=\"option selectize-option\">' + escape(item.label) + '</div>';
  }
}")


shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    tags$head(tags$style(HTML(css))),
    selectizeInput(
      "input",
      "Choose",
      choices = c("a", "b", "c"),
      options = list(render = render)
    )
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {
  }
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pickerInput` from `shinyWidgets`

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)

ui <- fluidPage(
  pickerInput('id', 'Select Input', letters[1:3])
)
server <- function(input, output) {}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Comment: Are you seeing the same behavior with selectInput? What changed to cause this? I don’t think it is a change in the shiny package because I’m using the same package version. I was actually already aware that pickerInput doesn’t seem to share this behavior. But for apps with a lot of selectInputs, I’d rather not have to convert them all to pickerInput.

Comment: I see the options highlighted with slight grey color. I don't know if this was always the case or something changed recently. If you don't want to change to  `pickerInput` then adding some css might help to color the selected option with `selectInput`.